# Prefer 5GHz to 2.4Ghz band for specific wifi network (SSID) without using BSSID or for all networks?

Tags: linux, debian, wifi

Is there a way to prefer 5GHz band to 2.4GHz band (without disabling 2.4GHz altogether) for a specific wifi network (SSID) without setting BSSID or failing that for all networks?

I am using Mint 18.3 with Cinnamon 3.6.7's network manager.

I have a new Dell XPS 13. Kernel is 4.13.0-26-generic.

```
lspci | grep -i wireless
3a:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 32)
```

Background: 
The routers are in an office so I cannot alter their setup. I can only do things on my laptop. Also it is the initial connection more than roaming that I am thinking of. When I connect to an SSID in the office at my desk, I would like it to prefer 5GHz to 2.4GHz (because the 5GHz signal is stronger), but right now it connects to 2.4GHz by default. Although I can set the BSSID to a specific 5GHz one which works well at my desk, this is not a good solution because if I do move around the building, I have to unset it again to allow roaming to work. I was advised by IT support to choose the prefer 5GHz option in Windows, but I am running Linux.

For Windows:
On right side of taskbar > Right-click on network icon
Choose Open Network and Sharing Center
Select Change adapter settings
Find your Wi-Fi connection (your connections will differ)
Right-click, Properties > Configure > Preferred Band to 5.2GHz
Click OK

Comment: We need more info : what kind of wifi adapter are you using ? How do you connect to these access points (NetworkManager, command line tool...) ? Which version of Linux Mint are you running, using which kernel ... ?

Comment: Hi @ThomasGros I have added the information. Let me know if there is anything else you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are dealing with limitations of the Wifi protocol.

Several corporate wifi vendors like Meru have non-standard technologic mitigation measures in place for dealing with that kind of limitations, because usually leaving that kind of decisions for the client is not the ideal situation, and even then they are not free of problems.

With some solutions, for instance OpenWRT or other corporate solutions, you can define threshold points/distance where the AP will force a drop of the client device from 5GHz to 2.4GHz; however a roaming client that already dropped to the 2.4GHz band, coming back again near the AP is not guaranteed to go back to 5GHz *without user intervention*. Meru controllers/APs have a measure/hack to try to force client devices moving back to 5GHz in those situations, and it creates a lot of problems.

As for the Dell XPS 13, it has known wifi problems because the USB C interface is right next to the wifi. Dell has not done anything about it in 3 or 4 generations of the hardware besides putting aluminum foil between the two devices in latter models, and deploying an unfortunate firmware patch for decreasing the maximum allowed potency of the wifi interface in all models.

At most on the linux side, you can monitor the wifi interface every couple of minutes in whitelisted SSIDs for when the connection is in 2.4GHz mode and force a drop of the connection when the quality is better; it is an ugly hack and I would not go down that road.

Often the solution that offers the more control for the client to select between 2.4GHz and 5GHz is having different SSIDs for the two technologies.

Saying that, at home I have both of them with the same SSID, and on the OpenWRT AP side, a threshold of 7 meters where 5GHz clients are forced to drop to the 2.4GHz band (because of walls).

To specify priorities for the initial scanning between 5GHz and 2.4GHz band, you can add to your `/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf` file the following directive:

```
scan_freq=5500 5520 ...
```

or

```
freq_list=....
```

However, I actually have no idea of the adqueate frequency values for your infra-structure to put in there. Ask for the advice of your IT team. I would fudge the normal values putting their active frequencies first.

Comment: I forgot to say that the routers are in an office so I cannot alter their setup. I can only do things on the Linux side. Also it is the initial connection rather than roaming that I am thinking of. When I connect to an SSID I would like it to prefer 5GHz to 2.4GHz (because the 5GHz signal is stronger), but right now it connects to 2.4GHz by default (although I can set the BSSID to a specific 5GHz one). Setting the BSSID doesn't work well because if I do move around the building, I have to unset it again. I will add this into the question.

Comment: It is not normal selecting 2.4GHz by default unless you are far away from the 5Ghz APs. What you are saying does not change my answer. I however find it one you getting by default in the 2.4GHz if both bands are equally strong.

Comment: It's strange though because the signal is clearly weaker when it actually connects to the 2.4GHz one and I used a tool to check the strengths of the different BSSIDs which also showed that one BSSID is stronger. I was told by IT support here to use the setting prefer 5GHz in Windows, but I am running Linux.

Comment: Your edit to add info on scan_freq in /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf looks promising. Is that used by Cinnamon's network manager or will I have to use the CLI? Is there a tool I can run to get those frequencies?

Comment: There should be a tool, maybe running the actual wpa_supplicant. I have not one active at the moment to check it out.

Comment: I found a tool "sudo iwlist scanning | grep -A 3 Address" so to confirm the order of the frequencies listed under scan_freq or freq_list determines which BSSID will be used?

Comment: Also does Mint's network manager use wpa_supplicant or will I have to disable using network manager and use wpa_supplicant instead?

Comment: @mcarans I have dealt with end user wifi configurations in Linux for a good while, the details are a bit fuzzy.  I am afraid wont be able to help you more, I just intended to give you a way to go on on yourself.

Comment: Note this q+a for possible frequency values: https://superuser.com/questions/1289185/how-do-you-find-possible-values-for-freq-list-and-or-scan-freq-in-wpa-supplicant#1289440

Comment: @Piskvor Indeed, good call. In my answer, I  was more worried of prioritising the frequencies in use by the OP's local infra-structure, edited slightly the answer for it to be clearer.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro: That's what I was trying to find, originally. Then I needed to know available values :)

Comment: So from what I understand, the `scan_freq` should basically include every possible channel *(i.e. because each channel has a different frequency, and channels typically are being changed dynamically depending on what channels are already used by other routers)*. That's a lot of frequencies to include…

Answer (score 2):

Although not for specific SSID, but *(given the lack of answers here)* you can steer `iwd` backend to prefer 5Ghz over 2.4Ghz in general.

`iwd` is an alternative *(to the default `wpa_supplicant`)* WiFi backend. [NetworkManager integration with `iwd`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NetworkManager#Using_iwd_as_the_Wi-Fi_backend) is still experimental, so there may be some gaps in functionality, but for basic WiFi usage it seems to work fine.

`iwd` already prefers 5Ghz over 2.4Ghz, but you can enforce that further. [There's `BandModifier5Ghz` option](https://man.archlinux.org/man/iwd.config.5#Rank), a floating-point value that increases priority of 5Ghz points over 2.4Ghz and 6Ghz. Default is `1.0`. In the example below I set it to `9.0`, which in my experiments seems enough to stop it from falling back to 2.4Ghz.¹

Example: create file `/etc/iwd/main.conf` with:

```ini
[Rank]
BandModifier5Ghz=9.0
```

…then restart `iwd`. NM doesn't seem to restart it when it's restarted itself *(as I mentioned the integration is still WIP)*, so the simplest way might be to just reboot.

---

1: The exact upper limits are undocumented. Looking [at the source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/wireless/iwd.git/tree/src/scan.c?id=320041eaf2c8d8228f0763f2e259308858060e15#n1669), it does some complicated calculation by multiplying the `BandModifier5Ghz` with other factors such as network utilization. However, in the same function it caps the value to `USHRT_MAX`, so presumably if you want to go as high as possible, you can set `BandModifier5Ghz=65535` *(I tested that it works)*.